# How do I stop the page from rendering every time I scroll?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, components

I think that I am accidentally refreshing this every time a scroll happens, which is maybe rendering the page on every change.

I think that the issue is that the `window.addeventlistener` gets called the first time and never unmounts, and then the second time `animator` is called, it mounts and unmounts it's own event listener, leaving the first in place.

I know `useEffect` is rendering every time `scrollPosition` changes, my goal was to stop `scrollPosition` from changing essentially after the first scroll.

The problem here (aside from any performance issues) is that there are components that have animations, which reset every time the `scrollPosition` changes.

my question is: **How do I stop the rendering after the first time the `useEffect` runs on the `scrollPosition` change?**

```
function App() {

  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.scrollY;
    setScrollPosition(position);
  };

  function animator() {
    if (!animating) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
    }

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
     };
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    animator();
  }, [scrollPosition]);
}
```

I have tried moving the event listener to basically every possible other position, creating new functions to handle it, and used the `animating` boolean to try and prevent `scrollPosition` from changing, but alas it has not worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the useMemo hook. This video will explain how you can implement it in your code [https://youtu.be/THL1OPn72vo]